# How to Plot a US state in R?

Tags: r

I can plot data for a particular state in the whole US map. But I want to plot only the state map  with the data (Oklahoma).

How can I do it in R?

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
 geom_point(data=stations,aes(x=long,y=lat),,colour="red",)+
 ggtitle("Distribution of Flash Flood Events in CONUS")+
 xlab('Longitude')+
 ylab('Latitude')



dput(stations)
structure(list(coop = c(340017L, 340179L, 340256L, 340292L, 340548L, 
340593L, 340908L, 341243L, 341504L, 341724L, 341828L, 342678L, 
342912L, 342944L, 343497L, 343628L, 343821L, 343871L, 344055L, 
344204L, 344235L, 344298L, 344573L, 344766L, 344861L, 345063L, 
345509L, 345779L, 345855L, 346130L, 346139L, 346278L, 346629L, 
346638L, 346670L, 346926L, 346935L, 347012L, 347254L, 348501L, 
348677L, 349395L, 349422L, 349445L), lat = c(34.7864, 34.5903, 
34.2208, 34.1714, 36.7683, 36.8125, 36.7236, 36.8003, 35.1756, 
36.7747, 36.3225, 34.0003, 36.4194, 35.2164, 35.6267, 36.5914, 
35.8161, 35.585, 36.0942, 34.9894, 35.0567, 36.8589, 36.7222, 
36.9031, 35.8583, 34.6097, 34.8911, 35.505, 36.8833, 35.7781, 
36.2283, 36.8914, 36.1217, 35.4253, 35.6239, 34.7253, 36.6692, 
36.2886, 35.0539, 36.1175, 35.9369, 34.1747, 35.52, 35.4814), 
    long = c(-96.685, -99.3344, -95.615, -97.1294, -96.0261, 
    -100.5308, -102.4806, -99.6403, -98.5794, -98.3583, -95.5808, 
    -96.3686, -97.8747, -99.8628, -98.3225, -101.6181, -97.395, 
    -99.3953, -97.835, -99.0525, -96.3861, -101.2172, -97.7903, 
    -102.965, -97.9294, -98.4572, -99.5017, -96.9767, -94.8833, 
    -95.3339, -99.17, -97.0586, -98.315, -96.3033, -96.025, -97.2814, 
    -96.3472, -97.2897, -94.6264, -97.095, -94.9644, -97.9964, 
    -98.6986, -95.2039), elev = c(309.4, 420.6, 143.3, 268.2, 
    217.9, 751.3, 1259.7, 588.3, 451.4, 359.7, 179.2, 182.9, 
    379.5, 627.9, 487.7, 1008.9, 338.3, 554.7, 357.8, 474.3, 
    260.6, 912.9, 318.5, 1325.9, 320, 350.5, 486.2, 281.9, 245.4, 
    157.9, 576.1, 347.5, 370.3, 285, 197.2, 286.5, 254.5, 312.4, 
    134.1, 272.8, 259.1, 278, 493.2, 167.6), state = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "OK", class = "factor"), 
    name = structure(1:44, .Label = c("ADA", "ALTUS IRIG RSCH STN", 
    "ANTLERS", "ARDMORE", "BARTLESVILLE MUNI AP", "BEAVER", "BOISE CITY 2 E", 
    "BUFFALO 2 SSW", "CARNEGIE 5 NE", "CHEROKEE", "CLAREMORE 2 ENE", 
    "DURANT", "ENID", "ERICK", "GEARY", "GOODWELL RSCH STN", 
    "GUTHRIE 5S", "HAMMON 3 SSW", "HENNESSEY 4 ESE", "HOBART MUNI AP", 
    "HOLDENVILLE 2SSE", "HOOKER", "JEFFERSON", "KENTON", "KINGFISHER", 
    "LAWTON", "MANGUM", "MEEKER 5 W", "MIAMI", "MUSKOGEE", "MUTUAL", 
    "NEWKIRK 1NW", "OKEENE", "OKEMAH", "OKMULGEE WTR WKS", "PAULS VALLEY 4 WSW", 
    "PAWHUSKA", "PERRY", "POTEAU WTR WKS", "STILLWATER 2 W", 
    "TAHLEQUAH", "WAURIKA", "WEATHERFORD", "WEBBERS FALLS 5 WSW"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("coop", "lat", "long", 
"elev", "state", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit*. update according to comment

Since Geekuna is using `ggplot`, I am giving an answer for `ggplot`

```
 m = map_data('state', region = 'Oklahoma')

 ggplot() + 
 geom_polygon( data=m, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
 geom_point(data=stations,aes(x=long,y=lat),,colour="red",)+
 geom_text(data=stations, aes(x=long, y=lat,label=name), size=2, hjust=-0.1) +
 ggtitle("Distribution of Flash Flood Events in CONUS")+
 xlab('Longitude')+
 ylab('Latitude')+
 coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Yours is the most clean and direct answer to the question, but you should *always* use `coord_fixed()` with maps in ggplot to avoid the distortion you are getting.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with a small thing? I wanted to add the name of the stations to the map as well as given in 'name'. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `maps` package.  There are a lot of simple options for the appearance of the map. Here are two very basic ones.  As far as this problem goes, the `maps` package doesn't differ from `ggplot2` very much at all, other than the fact that it's easier to code in `maps`.

```
> library(maps)
> par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
> map('state', region = 'Oklahoma')
> map('county', region = 'Oklahoma')
```

[image]

**ADD:**
Since you added the data, here is an exaggerated plot which assumes the data is called `dat`.

```
> map('county', region = 'Oklahoma')
> with(dat, points(lat ~ long, pch = 19, col = 'red'))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I modify the existing code to use this? Thanks!

Comment: Please post some of your data (using `dput(data)`) and I can show you.

Comment: THanks. I have added the data. Could you help me do this in ggplot by modifying my code?  Thanks.

Comment: There is no real difference.  I mean, it's a map. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use `ggcounty` package if you want to show county for state as well.

```
library(devtools)
install_github(repo="hrbrmstr/ggcounty")
library(ggcounty)

ok <- ggcounty("Oklahoma")

ok$gg
```

[image]

**Edited after dput from OP**

```
ok$gg +
  geom_point(data=stations,aes(x=long,y=lat),,colour="red",size=5)+
  ggtitle("Distribution of Flash Flood Events in CONUS")+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

You may want to remove xlab and ylab. I hope it helped you.

Comment: Can You help me integrate it with the ggplot code please? Thanks! The library looks great.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggcounty’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Comment: You need to install package `devtools`. Then use the following command 
`install_github(repo="hrbrmstr/ggcounty")`. You can install devtools using `install.packages("devtools")`. I updated the answer to include your data.

Comment: It doesn't work. You should release that as a R repo. Looks fantastic though. Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘install_github’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Comment: You might need to install or may be update `devtools` first. I also got some error while installing this package. The devtools version I have is `devtools_1.5`. The above code was for R version 3.0.2. I am not the author of this package BTW. This seems like a good package which I recently discovered. "https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggcounty"

Comment: Thanks! I have all updated packages. So maybe there is a problem.

Comment: It seems that you haven't loaded `devtools`. Try the following:

`install.packages("devtools");
library(devtools);
install_github("hrbrmstr/ggcounty")`

Comment: I'm hoping to dedicate some more time this wk to expand the functionality. If folks have issues or feature requests, pls use the github issues section. Be glad to try to accommodate what I can.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yeah, seems like package is nice. Haven't done a lot of testing though. Just learned about this package and answered question using the package.