# How can I make the label not overlap the point in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code to plot the following figure:

```
m = map_data('state', region = 'Oklahoma')
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=m, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=stations,aes(x=long,y=lat),,colour="red",)+
  geom_text(data=stations,aes(x=,long,y=lat,label=name,fill = NULL, size=1))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_fixed()
```

How can I stop the text from overlapping over the ticker?  Thanks!

[image]

---

Data

```
dput(stations)
structure(list(coop = c(340017L, 340179L, 340256L, 340292L, 340548L, 
340593L, 340908L, 341243L, 341504L, 341724L, 341828L, 342678L, 
342912L, 342944L, 343497L, 343628L, 343821L, 343871L, 344055L, 
344204L, 344235L, 344298L, 344573L, 344766L, 344861L, 345063L, 
345509L, 345779L, 345855L, 346130L, 346139L, 346278L, 346629L, 
346638L, 346670L, 346926L, 346935L, 347012L, 347254L, 348501L, 
348677L, 349395L, 349422L, 349445L), lat = c(34.7864, 34.5903, 
34.2208, 34.1714, 36.7683, 36.8125, 36.7236, 36.8003, 35.1756, 
36.7747, 36.3225, 34.0003, 36.4194, 35.2164, 35.6267, 36.5914, 
35.8161, 35.585, 36.0942, 34.9894, 35.0567, 36.8589, 36.7222, 
36.9031, 35.8583, 34.6097, 34.8911, 35.505, 36.8833, 35.7781, 
36.2283, 36.8914, 36.1217, 35.4253, 35.6239, 34.7253, 36.6692, 
36.2886, 35.0539, 36.1175, 35.9369, 34.1747, 35.52, 35.4814), 
    long = c(-96.685, -99.3344, -95.615, -97.1294, -96.0261, 
    -100.5308, -102.4806, -99.6403, -98.5794, -98.3583, -95.5808, 
    -96.3686, -97.8747, -99.8628, -98.3225, -101.6181, -97.395, 
    -99.3953, -97.835, -99.0525, -96.3861, -101.2172, -97.7903, 
    -102.965, -97.9294, -98.4572, -99.5017, -96.9767, -94.8833, 
    -95.3339, -99.17, -97.0586, -98.315, -96.3033, -96.025, -97.2814, 
    -96.3472, -97.2897, -94.6264, -97.095, -94.9644, -97.9964, 
    -98.6986, -95.2039), elev = c(309.4, 420.6, 143.3, 268.2, 
    217.9, 751.3, 1259.7, 588.3, 451.4, 359.7, 179.2, 182.9, 
    379.5, 627.9, 487.7, 1008.9, 338.3, 554.7, 357.8, 474.3, 
    260.6, 912.9, 318.5, 1325.9, 320, 350.5, 486.2, 281.9, 245.4, 
    157.9, 576.1, 347.5, 370.3, 285, 197.2, 286.5, 254.5, 312.4, 
    134.1, 272.8, 259.1, 278, 493.2, 167.6), state = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "OK", class = "factor"), 
    name = structure(1:44, .Label = c("ADA", "ALTUS IRIG RSCH STN", 
    "ANTLERS", "ARDMORE", "BARTLESVILLE MUNI AP", "BEAVER", "BOISE CITY 2 E", 
    "BUFFALO 2 SSW", "CARNEGIE 5 NE", "CHEROKEE", "CLAREMORE 2 ENE", 
    "DURANT", "ENID", "ERICK", "GEARY", "GOODWELL RSCH STN", 
    "GUTHRIE 5S", "HAMMON 3 SSW", "HENNESSEY 4 ESE", "HOBART MUNI AP", 
    "HOLDENVILLE 2SSE", "HOOKER", "JEFFERSON", "KENTON", "KINGFISHER", 
    "LAWTON", "MANGUM", "MEEKER 5 W", "MIAMI", "MUSKOGEE", "MUTUAL", 
    "NEWKIRK 1NW", "OKEENE", "OKEMAH", "OKMULGEE WTR WKS", "PAULS VALLEY 4 WSW", 
    "PAWHUSKA", "PERRY", "POTEAU WTR WKS", "STILLWATER 2 W", 
    "TAHLEQUAH", "WAURIKA", "WEATHERFORD", "WEBBERS FALLS 5 WSW"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("coop", "lat", "long", 
"elev", "state", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

Comment: I followed all directions, put a reproducible example, and received a very helpful answer. But there are a lot of ****hurt SOers who will downvote the hell out of every single thing for no apparent reason. Hope some corrective action is taken for this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels can still overlap each other, but they can be offset from the dots.

The command below adds some transparency, an offset to the text position, and makes it left justified.

```
 geom_text(data=stations,aes(x=long+.05,y=lat,label=name,fill = NULL, size=1,hjust=0,alpha=.5))
```

[image]

To manually adjust the position of some labels in ggplot, you can add an "overlap" field containing a small offset to administer to each latitude:

```
overlapDOWN = c("JEFFERSON","HENNESSEY 4 ESE","GUTHRIE 5S","WEATHERFORD")
overlapUP = c("GEARY","STILLWATER 2 W","ADA","LAWTON")
stations$overlap=0
stations$overlap[stations$name %in% overlapUP] = .05
stations$overlap[stations$name %in% overlapDOWN] = -.05
```

Then use:

```
 geom_text(data=stations,aes(x=long+.05,y=lat+overlap,label=name,fill = NULL, hjust=0,alpha=.5),size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you can see the data here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206834/how-to-plot-a-us-state-in-r

Comment: I have also added the data.

Comment: Better. But lots of overlapping still. :(

Comment: If you want something to adaptively adjust the text if there will be overlap, then it would get pretty complicated... Maybe someone else has a "jitter" solution...

Comment: Thank you. I am open to a completely different solution as well. All I need is the points and the labels in a readable way.

Comment: If this is for a one-time product, it looks like there are only 6 labels that overlap noticeable. You could make an Offset variable that you add to Latitude which is mostly zeroes, but with some +/- 0.05 values for the names in the overlapping list.

Comment: Yes it is. Could you add that part of the code please?

Comment: You can add it anywhere after `stations` is defined and before you call `ggplot`. It is just adding another value to the data.frame which you access inside the plot (where it says `+overlap`). You can of course modify those offset values and the names of the cities you wish to include.

Comment: How can I pull down Guthrie and Altus down a little?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51140/discussion-between-beroe-and-geekuna-matata)

Comment: I decided to downvote based on this dialog. It annoys me greatly when questioners fail to acknowledge helpful answers. I would add that that for base graphics there is a 'plotrix' function with a strange name like `thigmophobe` that does do some sort of adaptive label placement.

Comment: @BondedDust What are you talking about? I have accepted the answer and this solved my problem. Does SO have to be unfriendly to everyone to prove a point?

Comment: At the time of my downvote, there was no acceptance, not even an upvote for an obviously useful answer. Why do new users seem to be so ungrateful for the efforts of the volunteers?

Comment: Umm...Maybe because sometimes newbies like us may have forgotten? You could have easily asked me to accept and I would have done it. Easier to be nice to newbies than act like you own this town. You didn't add anything to this answer, beroe did. So don't need nudging from you.

Answer (score 0):

`geom_text_repel` from `library(ggrepel)` will automatically move the labels to prevent them from overlapping and it will connect the label to the starting position with a line if the label is moved too far away from its starting point.

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=m, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=stations,aes(x=long,y=lat),,colour="red",)+
  geom_text_repel(data=stations,aes(x=,long,y=lat,label=name,fill = NULL, size=1))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_fixed()
```

[Figure with non-overlapping labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIYnw.png)